# How to show ldapatuh node jpegPhoto?

Tags: node.js, ldap, jpeg, ldapauth

I use ldapauth-fork in node.js to take a user information in ldap but when I try to take a user.jpegPhoto why can't it show this image?

I've tried this:

```
 const jpeg = Buffer.from(user.jpegPhoto, 'binary')
 fs.writeFileSync("foto.jpeg", jpeg);
```

And this:

```
var img64 = Buffer.from(user.jpegPhoto).toString('base64');
var foto = "<div><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,"+img64+"'/></div>"
fs.appendFile('index.html', foto, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
     console.log('Saved!');
  });
```

This is all node.js code:

```
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
var LdapAuth = require('ldapauth-fork');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var qs = require('querystring');

var username = "MOCKUSERNAME";
var password = "MOCKPASSWORD";

server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {

    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log("POST");
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
            //console.log(body);
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            var data = qs.parse(body);
            var userDecode = Buffer.from(data.username, 'base64').toString('ascii');
            var passDecode = Buffer.from(data.password, 'base64').toString('ascii'); 

            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'image/jpeg'});

            if (data.username && data.password) {

                var options = {
                   url:                'XXXXXX',
                   bindDN:             'XXXXX',
                   bindCredentials:    'XXXXX',
                   searchBase:         'XXXXX',
           includeRaw: true,
                   searchFilter:       '(aoldapkey=*' + userDecode + ')'
                   //  reconnect: true
                }
                var ldap = new LdapAuth(options);
                ldap.authenticate(userDecode, passDecode, function(err, user) {
                   if (err) {
                        console.log("login Error: " + err);
                        res.write(JSON.stringify({ success : false, message :     'Authentication failed', serverError: err }));
                            res.end('');
                       } else if(!user.uid) {
                        console.log("user not found Error: " + err);
                        res.write(JSON.stringify({ success : false, message :         
    'Authentication failed, user not found', serverError: err }));
                            res.end();
                       } else if(user.uid) {
                          console.log("success : user "+ user.uid +" found ");
                          var userJsonObject = {
                              success : true,
                              user: {
                                  uid : user.uid,
                                  cn: user.cn,
                                  givenName: user.givenName,
                                  sn: user.sn,
                                  title: user.title,
                                  mobile: user.mobile,
                                  mail: user.mail,
                                  aoJobPosition: user.aoJobPosition,
                                  jpegPhoto: user.jpegPhoto
                              }
                          }
    //------------------------------dont see the image in index.html
                /*var img64 = Buffer.from(user.jpegPhoto).toString('base64');
                var foto = "<div><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,"+img64+"'/>    
    </div>"
                fs.appendFile('index.html', foto, function (err) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  console.log('Saved!');
                });*/
    //--------------------------------
                          res.write(JSON.stringify(userJsonObject);
                          res.end();
                       }
                    });
                } else {
                res.write(JSON.stringify({ success : false, message : 'You must     
    specify a valid username and password'}));
                    res.end();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            var html = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(html);
        }
    });
    server.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log("Caught server error: ");
        console.log(err.stack);
    });

    port = 3000;
    host = '127.0.0.1';
    server.listen(port, host);
    console.log('Listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
```

This is all node.js code I use ldapauth-fork in node.js to take a user information in ldap but when i try to take a user.jpegPhoto y can´t show this image.

This is index.html :

```html
<div><img src='data:imag/*;base64, 77x73..........3vv70='/></div>
```

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyRbh.png)

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you expect the image to be "shown", and what happens instead?

Comment: The ldap returns an image to me but I can't show it in any way. I need it to put it on a website. if I open the jpeg that it generates for me, some characters similar to these ���� come up, and it tells me that the photo is corrupted.

Comment: What program are you using to open foto.jpeg? Can you post the contents of index.html?

Comment: i can´t post all code, i use to open the jpge in windows photo viewer but when i open in notepad++ i see these ���� and in other pc conected to ldap when take de jpegPhoto don´t see this charset, y tray to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/legacy-encoding to decode.

Comment: If you open a jpeg file in a text editor, you should expect to see garbled text. The reason I'd like to see the HTML is to find out whether the image was properly base64-encoded. If so, you should be able to see the image in a web browser looking at index.html.

Comment: In one of the examples I gave I did that but it didn't work, I don't see the image. If you look at the code that is commented on, you can see that I put it that way and it didn't work.<div><img src='data:imag/*;base64, 77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAECAAABAAEAAO+/ve+/vQBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQ.............................................9eu+/vUVlV2Lvv73vv73vv73vv70='/></div>

Comment: Looks fine to me... have you tried using a base64 decoder to test whether the base64 content converts back to an image correctly?

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter . i try this but, if you see here                                                                                      
 var img64 = Buffer.from(user.jpegPhoto).toString('base64');
                var foto = "<div><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,"+img64+"'/>    
    </div>"
                fs.appendFile('index.html', foto, function (err) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  console.log('Saved!');
                });                and when i open de index .html dont see the photo

Comment: Again, it's really difficult to debug without an example of an index.html that doesn't work. I'd need the full code without the base64 shortened.

Comment: the node.js server only return all userdata "res.write(JSON.stringify(userJsonObject)", in frontend i use angular 4 with typescript, but i try with node to append in index.html a img with src in base64 but the user.jpegPhoto not shown.I've tried a lot of ways but I think it has to do with the LDAPAUTH library I downloaded with npm. https://github.com/trentm/node-ldapauth/issues/27